# Getting timeout when running a stored procedure which makes rest API calls - How to increase timeout?

Tags: sql-server, xmlhttprequest, timeout, sql-server-2017, msxml6

A customer is on SQL Server 2017 and is executing a stored procedure that makes an API call to a server and fetches data.

Sometimes (when the API call is intensive on the remote server and takes too long to return data) the call times out at the customer's end around the 30 second mark.

The error they receive is:

> 0x80072EE2 msxml6.dll The operation timed out

Upon looking online, this seems like a default timeout on the `xmlhttp` client that SQL Server uses.

How to increase the timeout pertaining to the `xmlhttp` client?
Would increasing the stored procedure timeout take care of this?

Comment: Quite simply: don’t call APIs on some web site from inside a stored procedure. Whatever is calling the stored procedure, have THAT call the API. When was the last time they updated msxml6? 2009? It’s time to improve your architecture instead of scrambling to increase a timeout.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for your suggestion. I'll pass it along!